# AS3: Main stage listener for ProgressEvent?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Can I add a ProgressEvent listener to the stage?
I don't see it in any of the auto-complete options when I am typing in Flex.
What do people normally do to get a progress readout of the entire main runner's loading progress?

I try the following, which is where I would expect to see the ProgressEvent options pop up:

```
stage.addEventListener(
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding it to **[loaderInfo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html)**.

[image]

something like:

```
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
```

Also , if you're using the framework, you should probably extend the DownloadProgressBar.
I remember [this old tutorial](http://www.onflex.org/flexapps/components/CustomPreloader/SWF/srcview/), but surely there must be plenty online.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am trying to keep this project AS only.  I will look into options with loaderInfo.  Is the preferred AS3 method in this case still to use a main SWF loading container that loads your main app runner SWF after you have compiled it?

Comment: no flex framework ? then it's loaderInfo if you want to listen for the progress of the main swf, and containerLoaderInfo for a Loader object

Comment: Hm; this works, but I still get a huge delay between the time at which my site loads and receiving any feedback from the progress handler.  I draw some text on the screen, indicating the percentage of load completion, and it doesn't seem to do much because the progress advances so quickly.  FWIW, I am loading locally and all my Loader() requests and handled after the site has loaded. How can I test this otherwise?  Do I have to go live with my site??

Comment: in the flash ide you have a simulate download option, but for flex, either you embed a large file just to check the preloader, or you use sloppy on your local test server: http://blog.betabong.com/2008/12/06/test-flex-throttled-simulate-download/

Comment: hm; doesn't work whether my site is live or not.  there is something else going on; please see my newly formulated question (reliant on the initial question for clarity) below.

Answer (score 1):

I have a new problem:

I use the following code to show the progress of the download of my site content:

```
    public function mainProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
    {
        var w:Number = e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal;
        _mainprog.graphics.clear();
        _mainprog.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        _mainprog.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, w * stage.stageWidth, 50);
        _mainprog.graphics.endFill(); 
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work. 
What happens is that the loaderInfo object *thinks* that the site has loaded before I am actually ready to display anything.  So what ends up happening (I think) is the site loads, the loader progress disappears before the initial page's graphics have fully loaded, and then there is a delay between when the completion of the loaderInfo object happens and the actual graphics appearing.

Has anyone else had this problem before?

Thanks...

Comment: Hi jml, if I got this right, you have one swf which is your site and you Embed assets to it, the mainProgress loader is added to this.loaderInfo, and there are no Loader objects ? My guesses are: 1. Your loader might show up a bit late starting at some percentage(say 30 for example), if that's the case 2. The preloader looks ok, shows a rectangle from 0 to stage's width, but there's minor delay between 100 percent and the actual graphics showing on screen. Am I close ?

Comment: i define some graphics to draw-- rectangles, textfields, x y coords calculated based on stage parameters, strings passed, colors for elements etc, add a tween with Tweener(), the Tweener()'s onComplete creates some more sprite/textual elements, graphical elements' listeners are added, stage listeners are added, then i add various children to the stage. this should all take some time to load.  i have a progress bar that should be appearing while this is all happening and then when it happens, the graphics should be initialized and added to the stage, then Tweens should occur.

Comment: in the last sentence i meant to say "...while all of this is being set up, and then when it happens..."